# Does 2E AD&D specify a change in scale for missile and spell ranges from outdoors to indoors?

Tags: adnd-2e, ranged-attack

In 2E AD&D, ranges for missiles and spells are by default given in yards. Does this ruleset ever specify a different conversion when used indoors/underground? Citation/reference desired.

Comment: Do you consider Combat&Tatics as 2e?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### No, not for missile or spell ranges

According to the AD&D 2e (Revised) Player's Handbook, missile and spell ranges have a set range in yards (PHB p.131, under Range):

> The first step in making a missile attack is to find the range from the attacker to the target. **This is measured in yards from one point to the other.** This distance is compared to the range categories for the weapon used (see Table 45 in Chapter 6: Money and Equipment).

The table in question (PHB p.95) specifies "Range (Yards)" and includes a summary of the rules, which makes no mention of any difference between dungeon and overland. There's no mention of a difference in the full missile weapons rules on p.131 either.

Likewise, the rules on spell range/area of effect (PHB p.168) say only that the spell specifies the range, and each spell has its own range specified in specific units, typically yards for range (e.g. *magic missile*, p.176, has a range of 60 yards + 10 yards per level).

AD&D 2e only changes scale for movement, not range. In contrast to range, which specifies a unit, characters have a movement rate as a flat number, which must be multiplied by a scale of feet or yards.<sup>1</sup> This doesn't apply to missile/spell range; yards are still yards when you're in a dungeon, you just walk more slowly indoors because, canonically,  you're being cautious and paying attention to your surroundings.

---

<sup>1. For the benefit of future readers finding this answer, that scale is 10x feet per round in a dungeon or combat (AD&D 2e revised PHB 128, 157), 10x yards per round otherwise (PHB 157) or 2x miles per 10-hour day overland (PHB 158).</sup>